# Rewrite config parameter with phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Is it possible to rewrite config parameter with phalcon?
I use ini File Type.
If not - tell me how to implement please.

Comment: I want to help, I do, but I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create ini file with php, it is possible, even w/o phalcon.

from PHP docs comments:

Read file : $ini = INI::read('myfile.ini');
Write file : INI::write('myfile.ini', $ini);

### custom INI class Features :

- support [] syntax for arrays
- support . in keys like bar.foo.something = value
- true and false string are automatically converted in booleans
- integers strings are automatically converted in integers
- keys are sorted when writing
- constants are replaced but they should be written in the ini file between braces : {MYCONSTANT}

  $val) {
                    if (is_array($val)) {
                        $string .= INI::write_get_string($ini[$key], $prefix.$key.'.');
                    } else {
                        $string .= $prefix.$key.' = '.str_replace("\n", "\\\n", INI::set_value($val))."\n";
                    }
                }
                return $string;
            }
            /**
             *  manage keys
             */
            static function set_value($val) {
                if ($val === true) { return 'true'; }
                else if ($val === false) { return 'false'; }
                return $val;
            }
            /**
             *  READ
             */
            static function read($filename) {
                $ini = array();
                $lines = file($filename);
                $section = 'default';
                $multi = '';
                foreach($lines as $line) {
                    if (substr($line, 0, 1) !== ';') {
                        $line = str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("\n", "", $line));
                        if (preg_match('/^\[(.*)\]/', $line, $m)) {
                            $section = $m[1];
                        } else if ($multi === '' && preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_.\[\]-]+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/i', $line, $m)) {
                            $key = $m[1];
                            $val = $m[2];
                            if (substr($val, -1) !== "\\") {
                                $val = trim($val);
                                INI::manage_keys($ini[$section], $key, $val);
                                $multi = '';
                            } else {
                                $multi = substr($val, 0, -1)."\n";
                            }
                        } else if ($multi !== '') {
                            if (substr($line, -1) === "\\") {
                                $multi .= substr($line, 0, -1)."\n";
                            } else {
                                INI::manage_keys($ini[$section], $key, $multi.$line);
                                $multi = '';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                $buf = get_defined_constants(true);
                $consts = array();
                foreach($buf['user'] as $key => $val) {
                    $consts['{'.$key.'}'] = $val;
                }
                array_walk_recursive($ini, array('INI', 'replace_consts'), $consts);
                return $ini;
            }
            /**
             *  manage keys
             */
            static function get_value($val) {
                if (preg_match('/^-?[0-9]$/i', $val)) { return intval($val); } 
                else if (strtolower($val) === 'true') { return true; }
                else if (strtolower($val) === 'false') { return false; }
                else if (preg_match('/^"(.*)"$/i', $val, $m)) { return $m[1]; }
                else if (preg_match('/^\'(.*)\'$/i', $val, $m)) { return $m[1]; }
                return $val;
            }
            /**
             *  manage keys
             */
            static function get_key($val) {
                if (preg_match('/^[0-9]$/i', $val)) { return intval($val); }
                return $val;
            }
            /**
             *  manage keys
             */
            static function manage_keys(& $ini, $key, $val) {
                if (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(.*)$/i', $key, $m)) {
                    INI::manage_keys($ini[$m[1]], $m[2], $val);
                } else if (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_-]+)\[(.*)\]$/i', $key, $m)) {
                    if ($m[2] !== '') {
                        $ini[$m[1]][INI::get_key($m[2])] = INI::get_value($val);
                    } else {
                        $ini[$m[1]][] = INI::get_value($val);
                    }
                } else {
                    $ini[INI::get_key($key)] = INI::get_value($val);
                }
            }
            /**
             *  replace utility
             */
            static function replace_consts(& $item, $key, $consts) {
                if (is_string($item)) {
                    $item = strtr($item, $consts);
                }
            }
        }

find out more here: https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file